# Changing language at runtime using SwiftGen

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

My app is supposed to support language change at runtime. I'm using SwiftGen 5.0. ViewControllers subscribe to language change notification and I've checked that the localisation function fires correctly. My overriden `tr` function looks like this:

```
fileprivate static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
    guard let bundle = LanguageManager.shared.bundle else {
        fatalError("Cannot find bundle!")
    }
    let format = NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: table, bundle: bundle, comment: "")
    let locale = Locale(identifier: LanguageManager.shared.currentLanguageKey!)
    return String(format: format, locale: locale, arguments: args)
}
```

The `bundle` is set like so:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentLanguageKey, ofType: "lproj") {
    bundle = Bundle(path: path)
}
```

However, the `tr` function returns mostly previous language strings. Only one out of all labels currently in memory refreshes. Setting a breakpoint inside the function and printing `bundle` returns

```
NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/ED5A6C7D-1807-4319-8817-45E693BC45E2/MyApp.app/en_US.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

which is the correct new language. After app restarts the language is set correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How does your app support language changes without the app getting killed/re-launched? Changing the device locale will terminate your app, so I don't see how you're planning on doing this via the native device locale, instead of some custom setting in your app. So it shouldn't matter that the locales from SwiftGen are memoized.

Comment: When language was changed, I posted a notification that called a function on all running applicable viewControllers, called `localize()`, that contained all localizable views setup (labels, images, tables, etc). That way the app could have its language changed at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can config lookupFunction params in swiftgen.yml file

```
strings:
  inputs:
    - en.lproj
  outputs:
    - templateName: structured-swift5
      params:
        lookupFunction: Localize_Swift_bridge(forKey:table:fallbackValue:)
      output: L10n-Constants.swift
```

in your project you just need implement lookupFunction,
your can use use Localize_Swift library

```
import Localize_Swift;
func Localize_Swift_bridge(forKey:String,table:String,fallbackValue:String)->String {
    return forKey.localized(using: table);
}
```

generated code may like this:

```
internal enum Localizable {
       internal static var baseConfig: String { return 
         L10n.tr("Localizable", "base config", fallback: #"Base Config"#) }}


extension L10n {
  private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg..., fallback value: String) -> String {
    let format = Localize_Swift_bridge(forKey:table:fallbackValue:)(key, table, value)
    return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
  }
}
```

https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Documentation/templates/strings/structured-swift5.md

https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Answer (score 10):

Okay, I found the problem. The stencil was generating static variables:

```
static let label = L10n.tr("Localizable", "registration_verify.pin_code.label")
```

Changing stencil to generate computed properties fixed the behaviour:

```
static var label: String { 
    return L10n.tr("Localizable", "registration_verify.pin_code.label")
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the answer and share your `.stencil`? Thanks!

Comment: Copy the whole Stencil from https://github.com/SwiftGen/templates/blob/6514109f188dc7a8b9ea4c7664b12a36394c4e59/templates/strings/structured-swift4.stencil

And replace line 29 with:
    {{accessModifier}} static var {{string.name|swiftIdentifier:"pretty"|lowerFirstWord|escapeReservedKeywords}} { {{enumName}}.tr("{{table}}", "{{string.key}}") }

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue caused by runtime localization/language changes in my Swift app. To address this, I followed [Kacper's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731410/3152121) solution and extended the internal extension as outlined below:

Swift L10n:

```
extension L10n {
    private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        // Custom Setup
        let storedLanguages = ["de", "en"]
        if let languages = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? [String],
           let language = languages.first,
           storedLanguages.contains(language),
           let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"),
           let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
        {
            return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
        }

        // Default Setup
        let format = Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: table)
        return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
    }
}
```

Origin Stencil:

```
// MARK: - Implementation Details

extension {{enumName}} {
    private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
        // Default Setup
        {% if param.lookupFunction %}
        let format = {{ param.lookupFunction }}(key, table)
        {% else %}
        let format = {{param.bundle|default:"Bundle.main"}}.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: table)
        {% endif %}
        return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
    }
}
```

Modified Stencil:

```
// MARK: - Implementation Details

extension {{enumName}} {
    private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
    // Custom Setup
    let storedLanguages = ["de", "en"]
    if let languages = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? [String],
       let language = languages.first,
       storedLanguages.contains(language),
       {% if param.lookupFunction %}
           let path = {{ param.lookupFunction }}.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"),
       {% else %}
           let path = {{param.bundle|default:"Bundle.main"}}.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj"),
       {% endif %}
       let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
       {
           return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: nil)
       }
    
    // Default Setup
    {% if param.lookupFunction %}
    let format = {{ param.lookupFunction }}(key, table)
    {% else %}
    let format = {{param.bundle|default:"Bundle.main"}}.localizedString(forKey: key, value: nil, table: table)
    {% endif %}
    return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
    }
}
```

The ideation was to enable the app to immediately utilize the newly addressed localized table without requiring any restart or reopening. I also used [Kacper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731410/3152121)'s solution with:

```
static var label: String { 
    return L10n.tr("Localizable", "registration_verify.pin_code.label")
}
```

Origin Stencil:

```
{{accessModifier}}static let {{string.name|swiftIdentifier:"pretty"|lowerFirstWord|escapeReservedKeywords}} = {{enumName}}.tr("{{table}}", "{{string.key}}")
```

Modified Stencil:

```
{{accessModifier}}static var {{string.name|swiftIdentifier:"pretty"|lowerFirstWord|escapeReservedKeywords}}: String {  {{enumName}}.tr("{{table}}", "{{string.key}}") }
```